# what is the meaning of みにまかせる?

Tags: meaning, particles, particle-に

I've came across this sentence many times in anime songs and I don't know what is the meaning of it and the kanji of it. does the み in there stand for 見?
also, what is the difference between that and みをまかせる if they were related? because I've heard both of them:

> 時にみをまかせるだけ

in One Piece's 1st ending

> ちからはいらない、みにまかせて

in Ousama Ranking's 2nd opening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This み is 身 or one's body. [～に身を任せる](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%BA%AB%E3%82%92%E4%BB%BB%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B) is a set phrase that means "to give oneself up to ～".

時に身を任せる ("to give oneself to time") is a little poetic expression, but it should imply "not to go against the flow of time", "to let what happens happen", etc.

身**に**任せて (身 is marked with に) is not a set phrase, but it should mean something along the lines of "(Stop thinking and) let your body do the work", "Listen to what your body says", "Leave it to your body", etc.